# Updating edmx using Visual Studio 2010 is very slow

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, edmx

I am using visual studio for development and when it comes to redraw an edmx file after some db changes it is taking ages to complete

I am trying to draw edmx for a Mysql database with 100 tables

Any suggestions or solutions to improve speed.
Is it because of some false design of Db or something with Visual Studio only

Comment: more likely its in your database design, maybe too complex to draw it in EF

Comment: most of tables have some foreign key relations . But is any specific known design rules that may affect speed

Comment: I think you should check performance of your MySql as write some querys, review your configuration, test on another server or PC ...

Almost cases make performance slow caused by database.

Answer (score 0):

You could change you connection to use a user that only sees a subset of tables. Gradually add extra tables as you need them.

**Edit **
If you have some major design issues,  then as you add groups of tables to your restricted user,  you will get an idea of where the problem is as the performance will drop considerably.

Comment: something on MySQL configuration??

Comment: The user that you are using can see all objects in the table. Create a new user and grant it access to just a subset of tables that you need to work with and are required for the business rules. 50 tables will be a lot more manageable

Comment: I highly doubt a user that has access to 100 tables versus 15 is causing the problem

Comment: @JibinMathew - did you get a resolution?

Comment: @Mike No solutions yet :(